# User data through indexing in lucene

Tags: lucene

I want to add to the document’s indexed field some user data that will be stripped by my custom tokenizer at run time and will be used by my custom filter later on,

I didn’t find a way to store user data in a public area so the filter could fetch it and process it.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance,
Lior.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in a different (stored) field.